# How can I make python say something in response to the users input if their input is below 18? And something else if it is above 18?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
badage = int("17")
goodage = int("18")
print("Check if you are eligible to vote in the United States")
users_age = int(input("How old are you?:"))
if users_age == badage :
    print("You are ineligible to vote in the United States")
if users_age == goodage :
    print("You are eligible to vote in the United States")
```

I am wondering how to make it say the same as badage and goodage for every number below 18 and above 18.

Comment: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't let the downvotes deter you, everyone starts somewhere! I would suggest you get a grip on the basics of Python, check out @jonrsharpe's link or pick up a beginners book

Comment: I'd suggest experimenting more with if statements

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<` and `>` operators:

```py
if users_age < goodage:
    print("You are ineligible to vote in the United States")
else:
    print("You are eligible to vote in the United States")
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
badage = 17
goodage = 18
print("Check if you are eligible to vote in the United States")
users_age = input("How old are you?:")
if int(users_age) <= badage :
    print("You are ineligible to vote in the United States")
else:
    print("You are eligible to vote in the United States")
```

Comment: Line 5 should be `if users_age <= badage`. The way you have it currently, 17 will print as eligible.